# indefinite trig substitution integral

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I am not able to understand how to get the solution for an integral. Substituting something like $\frac{1}{12}tan(\theta)$ seems to be the right thing to do, but I can't figure it out from there.

$$\int\frac{24dx}{(144x^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: Do you know $\tan^{2}\left(\,t\,\right) + 1 = \sec^{2}\left(\,t\,\right)$ and $\sec\left(\,t\,\right) = {1 \over \cos\left(\,t\,\right)}$ ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your substitution $x=\frac{1}{12}\tan(u)$. Then, $dx=\frac{1}{12}sec^2(u)du$, while the denominator becomes $(\tan^2(u)+1)^2=\sec^4(u)$. Thus, you have to integrate $2\cos^2(u)=(1+\cos(2u))$.